# CSS is automatically created in the sites/default/files/css directory

Tags: theming

I unchecked the *Aggregate and compress CSS files* option from admin/config/development/performance. Still, when I am inspecting the element CSS styles, the location is the same (sites/default/files/css).

How do I change CSS styles in this case?

Comment: have you tried clearing drupal cache?

Comment: yes i have checked. still the same

Comment: yes i effect is there css file name changed after "Aggregate and compress CSS files" unchecked. But location is same "sites/default/files/css"

Comment: try clearing your browser's cache and see if the issue still persists

Comment: Yes getting the same.

Comment: What is the location supposed to be? You are referring to a folder location and not file names.

Comment: "sites/default/files/css/construction-theme-preset1.css?o70j4t "  if css is not compressed

Comment: So then it is right, ain't it

Comment: No if i change any thing in this file, it shows effect but when i compress the css effect gone away.

Comment: Could it possibly be a CSS cascade in effect? Uncompressed the order of the cascade override is right, but compressed it is not. Only way to check is to see if your CSS makes it into the file, ie not whether it has an effect.

Comment: Is there any way to check CSS cascade present or not?